# Minimization problem involving the inverse of an affine matrix function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

I want  to minimize $v^T (A+I+UQU^*)^{-1} v$, subject to $Q$ and $A$ being positive semi-definite and ${\rm trace}(Q)<1$. Here, $v$ is a given vector with unit norm, that is, $\|v\|_2=1$.

Comment: Which variables here are kept fixed and which ones are you optimizing over?

Comment: the parameter to optimize is the matrix Q, its PSD symmetric and real with random value

Comment: What does it mean to say that you are optimizing with respect to a parameter that has "random value"?

Comment: @user44191   all data are random variable so Q will be combination of random matrix am looking for this relation, i have try to solve the problem based on KKT  theorem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rephrasing slightly, given (symmetric) matrix $\mathrm A \succeq \mathrm O_n$, we have the following minimization problem in (symmetric) matrix $\mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_n$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mathrm v^\top \left( \mathrm A + \mathrm I_n + \mathrm U \mathrm X \mathrm U^\top \right)^{-1} \mathrm v \\ \text{subject to} & \mbox{tr} (\mathrm X) \leq 1\\ & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_n\end{array}$$

Introducing a new optimization variable $y \in \mathbb R$ and rewriting in epigraph form,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & y\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm v^\top \left( \mathrm A + \mathrm I_n + \mathrm U \mathrm X \mathrm U^\top \right)^{-1} \mathrm v \leq y \\ & \mbox{tr} (\mathrm X) \leq 1\\ & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_n\end{array}$$

where the first inequality

$$y - \mathrm v^\top \left( \mathrm A + \mathrm I_n + \mathrm U \mathrm X \mathrm U^\top \right)^{-1} \mathrm v \geq 0$$

can be rewritten as the following linear matrix inequality (LMI) using the Schur complement

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A + \mathrm I_n + \mathrm U \mathrm X \mathrm U^\top & \mathrm v\\ \mathrm v^\top & y\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_{n+1}$$

and, thus, we obtain the following semidefinite program (SDP) in $\rm X$ and $y$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & y\\ \text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A + \mathrm I_n + \mathrm U \mathrm X \mathrm U^\top & \mathrm v\\ \mathrm v^\top & y\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_{n+1}\\ & \mbox{tr} (\mathrm X) \leq 1\\ & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_n\end{array}$$

Comment: Rodrigo de Azevedo can you please give me some reference to find my matrix X

Comment: @hichemhb you can use CVX or CVXPY to solve the SDP numerically.

Comment: @  Rodrigo de Azevedo can you please give me your email i wanna to contact you ?

Comment: it was about  a problem in optimization that i find using KKT method

Comment: @hichemhb Why not post a question on that problem on Math SE? The more (trained) eyes looking at it, the better.

Comment: @  Rodrigo de Azevedo  this is my proposition

Comment: so if the problem is to minimise sum(vi'(A+In+UXU⊤)^−1vi), can i use the same approach??

Comment: @hichemhb Similar, not same.

Comment: is there other approach  that i can use it ? @Rodrigo de Azevedo.

Comment: @hichemhb Replace $\rm v$ with $\mathrm V \mathbb 1$, where the columns of $\rm V$ are the $\mathrm v_i$'s. I may be wrong. Please verify.

Comment: @ Rodrigo de Azevedo i wanna to implement an algorithm to solve this problems can you give me some methods  references  or codes if its possible

Comment: @hichemhb Like I mentioned before, you can use CVXPY to solve the SDP. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a339790%20cvxpy).